# Run executable in Powershell with specific filenames as arguments

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to batch-convert heic images to png images using Powershell. What I have tried:

```
Get-ChildItem -Include ('*.HEIC', '*.heic') -File | & .\bin\vips.exe copy $_.Name "$(_.BaseName).png"
Pause
```

and

```
Get-ChildItem -Include ('*.HEIC', '*.heic') -File | & .\bin\vips.exe copy $_.Name ($_.BaseName + '.png')
Pause
```

Both times I'm getting an error `VipsForeignLoad: file ".png" does not exist` which tells me it treats ".png" as the first (and only) argument and ignores the object Name and Basename properties.

Comment: Piggy backing off @RetiredGeek's answer, try throwing it in a `foreach` loop: `Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.HEIC" -File | Foreach-Object {
   & .\bin\vips.exe copy $_.Name "$($_.BaseName).png" }`

Comment: `ForEach` did it!

Comment: I figured it would. Since it's not native to Powershell, it doesn't have a *Process Clause* to process the data as it streams. Most likely it's being read once as the *Begin Clause* and only executes one time.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for it to be *faster*, avoid the pipeline using the *grouping operator* `(...)` with the `.ForEach()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Just to be clear, the pipeline is what leads to a performance hit, meaning I could also gain that performance boost by using a [ForEach statement](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach.html)?

Comment: Yes, but the `.foreach()` method. Not to be confused for `foreach-object`, or `foreach(){}`. Minor performance hit but, it'll still make a difference.

Comment: Well `foreach(){}` is what I meant by a `ForEach` statement. That one is supposedly [the fastest out of the three](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/dptsfh/should_i_be_using_foreach_and_where_builtin/f5ynw62/) (with the .foreach method being close 2nd).

Comment: Big fan of Mr Lee, gonna disagree with the young fellow tho.

Comment: Minor performance difference, so it's not biggie between the top 2 mentioned in his post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a $. "$($_.BaseName).png" I would use -Filter vs -Include as it is more efficient.

Edited: Try this approach bypassing the Pipe and see if you get a different result. I've also added some additional code to insure everything is fully evaluated. If this approach works you can experiment with reducing come of the $() evaluation levels.

Also are you using Linux? Some of my googling led me to believe you might be. If so you should specify this in your tags for clarity.

```
Clear-Host
$x = Get-ChildItem -Filter "*.HEIC" -File
ForEach ($File in $x) {
  & .\bin\vips.exe copy "$($File.FullName)" $("$($File.BaseName)" + ".pdf")
}
```

Also note the file extension in the Filter is case insensitive so no need to repeat.

I'd also recommend adding the -Path parameter for clarity rather than assuming the default directory but that's just me.

HTH

Comment: Still getting the same error. `& .\bin\vips.exe copy test.HEIC test.png` goes through without issues. Thanks for the filter suggestion.

Comment: Give the updated answer a go. Please post back your console session if it doesn't work.

Comment: `ForEach` did it  (well, I ended up using ForEach-Object, but that's not crucial)! Didn't even have to do any of the insuring. Also thanks for the -Path suggestion. I'm trying to learn to do these things the proper way, so little pieces of advice like that (or the Filter part) are really helpful.